# A fast way for this matrix transformation?

Tags: r, matrix

Consider the code below to make a matrix `x`:

```
x = matrix(1:18, nrow=6, byrow=T)
x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
[4,]   10   11   12
[5,]   13   14   15
[6,]   16   17   18
```

Now I want `x` to be transformed to a new matrix, `x1`, in which each two following rows of x is taken as a new matrix, get transposed and finally all the transposed matrices are merged. This can be done by the following code:

```
x1 = c()
for (i in 1:(nrow(X)/2)) x1 = rbind(x1, t(x[((i-1)*2+1):(i*2),]))
x1
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    4
 [2,]    2    5
 [3,]    3    6
 [4,]    7   10
 [5,]    8   11
 [6,]    9   12
 [7,]   13   16
 [8,]   14   17
 [9,]   15   18
```

I wonder if this could be done by a member of `apply` family, because in my case `x` is very big and using `for` loop takes very long time to be performed. I also wonder if there are any other fast code for this transformation.

Edit: My `x` is with `1770000` rows and `12` columns. The number of rows is a multiplication of 590, so the resulting matrix `x1` should be with `36000` rows and `590` columns. I try to adjust @akrun code as:

```
x1 = do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, (seq_len(nrow(x))-1) %/% 590),
     matrix, ncol=590, byrow = TRUE))
```

But I receive the warning:

```
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
data length [12] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of columns [590]
```

Also `x1` is something like:

```
     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]       
[1,] Numeric,590 Numeric,590 Numeric,590 Numeric,590 Numeric,590 Numeric,590
[2,] Numeric,590 Numeric,590 Numeric,590 Numeric,590 Numeric,590 Numeric,590
[3,] Numeric,590 Numeric,590 Numeric,590 Numeric,590 Numeric,590 Numeric,590
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `split` `rbind` approach which would be faster

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, (seq_len(nrow(x))-1) %/% 2), matrix, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE))
```

#### Benchmarks

```
x <- matrix(1:180000, nrow = 60000, byrow = TRUE)

system.time({
x1 = c()
for (i in 1:(nrow(x)/2)) x1 = rbind(x1, t(x[((i-1)*2+1):(i*2),]))
})
# user  system elapsed 
#   6.78    0.56    7.39 


system.time({
  x2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, (seq_len(nrow(x))-1) %/% 2),
       matrix, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE))
   })
# user  system elapsed 
#   0.24    0.00    0.23 

identical(x1, x2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you. I find your code very fast and efficient, but seems I can not adjust it to my case correctly. Would you take a look at the Edit part of the question, please?

Comment: @M.Er  I looked at your edit.  It is working for me. `set.seed(24);
 x <- matrix(rnorm(1770000 * 12), nrow = 1770000);
lst <- split(x, (seq_len(nrow(x))-1) %/% 590);  x1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, matrix, ncol = 590, byrow = TRUE))`  It took 2.52 secs

Comment: I found the problem. For me `x` is actually a data frame. So I first transformed it to a matrix using `as.matrix()` and then my adjusted code worked fine.

Comment: @M.Er  If it is a data.frame, you don't have to convert it to `matrix`, just do `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, (seq_len(nrow(x))-1) %/% 2), function(x) t(x)))`

Comment: @Sathish Thanks for the comments.  It made me realize that the code could have been shorter

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by selecting every second row, flatten the result and combine it via `cbind`:

```
v1 <- x[(1:3)*2,]  
v2 <- x[1+(0:2)*2,]
cbind(as.vector(t(v1)), as.vector(t(v2)))
```

or -- more generally:

```
l <- length(x[,1])
v1 <- x[(1:(l/2))*2,]
v2 <- x[1+(0:(l/2 - 1))*2,]
cbind(as.vector(t(v1)), as.vector(t(v2)))
```

**Performance benchmarks:**

```
system.time({
   x <- matrix(1:180000, nrow = 60000, byrow = TRUE)     
   l <- length(x[,1])
   v1 <- x[(1:(l/2))*2,]    
   v2 <- x[1+(0:(l/2 - 1))*2,]
   cbind(as.vector(t(v1)), as.vector(t(v2)))    
})
 user  system elapsed 
  0.02    0.00    0.02
```

in comparison to the initial solution:

```
x <- matrix(1:180000, nrow = 60000, byrow = TRUE)

system.time({
   x1 = c()
   for (i in 1:(nrow(x)/2)) x1 = rbind(x1, t(x[((i-1)*2+1):(i*2),]))
   })
user  system elapsed 
5.83    0.00    5.85
```

Answer (score 1):

Using array dimensions and `aperm`:

```
x = matrix(1:18, nrow=6, byrow=T)

fun <- function(x, n) {
  cols <- ncol(x)
  rows <- nrow(x)
  dim(x) <- c(n, rows / n, cols)
  x <- aperm(x, c(3, 2 , 1))
  dim(x) <- c(rows * cols / n, n)
  x
}

fun(x, 2)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
#[2,]    2    5
#[3,]    3    6
#[4,]    7   10
#[5,]    8   11
#[6,]    9   12
#[7,]   13   16
#[8,]   14   17
#[9,]   15   18
```

Benchmarks:

```
library(microbenchmark)
x <- matrix(1:180000, nrow = 60000, byrow = TRUE) 
microbenchmark(
  "for" = {
    x1 = c()
    for (i in 1:(nrow(x)/2)) x1 = rbind(x1, t(x[((i-1)*2+1):(i*2),]))
    x1
  },
  array = fun(x, 2),
  split = do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, (seq_len(nrow(x))-1) %/% 2),
                               matrix, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)),
  indexing = {
    l <- length(x[,1])
    v1 <- x[(1:(l/2))*2,]    
    v2 <- x[1+(0:(l/2 - 1))*2,]
    cbind(as.vector(t(v1)), as.vector(t(v2)))  
  },
  times = 10
)
#Unit: microseconds
#    expr         min          lq         mean      median          uq         max neval cld
#     for 4313487.101 4333270.083 4557851.0186 4614434.395 4746682.820 4792838.589    10   c
#   array     655.037     690.119     730.7068     735.828     754.394     805.096    10 a  
#   split  133945.299  137704.718  148001.8562  146424.032  154185.373  175473.046    10  b 
#indexing    1369.482    1393.553    1803.0670    1424.027    1951.795    2984.285    10 a
```